# Purple beech tree disease, dieback or not enough water?

Tags: beech

There is this tree which I think is the Copper Beech tree or Purple Beech tree. It is a deciduous tree  starts with purple leaves in spring and the leaves green in summer.  Maybe it is a 'weeping beech tree' as some branches seem to curve downwards.

It is 7 ft tall right now and at the widest spot, it is 4 ft wide. The lower half is full of branches and leaves.

The upper half of the trunk is dry, and the bark is peeling off and the branches are dead. There are some spots on the bark.

I think it is dying because last year only the upper quarter was almost dead, but it is worse this year.

The picture shows a section of the bark that is about 2" in diameter.

Is it just the lack of enough water or a disease? It wasn't transplanted and it has been there for many years. I appreciate your suggestions.

[image: purple beech tree with peeling bark]